# What is the difference between cross-entropy and log loss error?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-entropy

What is the difference between cross-entropy and log loss error? The formulae for both seem to be very similar.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

They are essentially the same; usually, we use the term *log loss* for binary classification problems, and the more general *cross-entropy (loss)* for the general case of multi-class classification, but even this distinction is not consistent, and you'll often find the terms used interchangeably as synonyms.

From the [Wikipedia entry for cross-entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Cross-entropy_error_function_and_logistic_regression):

> The logistic loss is sometimes called cross-entropy loss. It is also known as log loss

From the [fast.ai wiki entry on log loss](http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Log_Loss#Log_Loss_vs_Cross-Entropy) [link is now dead]:

> Log loss and cross-entropy are slightly different depending on the context, but in machine learning when calculating error rates between 0 and 1 they resolve to the same thing.

From the [ML Cheatsheet](http://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/loss_functions.html):

> Cross-entropy loss, or log loss, measures the performance of a classification model whose output is a probability value between 0 and 1.

Comment: The fast.ai url currently does not work. [Here](https://www.fast.ai/posts/2019-06-28-course-p2v3.html#lesson-9-loss-functions-optimizers-and-the-training-loop) is the only blog in the fast.ai web site that refers to loss functions.

Comment: @dzegpi thanks, but I have already included a note in the post since Feb 2021, warning that the subject link is now dead (the link you have suggested does not seem to address the issue).