# How can I determine "loss function" for MLPClassifier in skilearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, classification

I want to use MLPClassifier of skilearn

```
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(50,), max_iter=10, alpha=1e-4,
                solver='sgd', verbose=10, tol=1e-4, random_state=1,
                learning_rate_init=.1)
```

I didn't find any parameter for the loss function, I want it to be `mean_squared_error`. Is it possible to determine it for the model?

Comment: By *definition*, since `MLPClassifier` is, well, a classifier, you cannot use MSE, since that would make the problem a regression one; for regression problems, you should use [`MLPRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html).

Comment: @desertnaut There might be issues with this particular software implementation, but MSE is an acceptable loss function for a classification problem. In that context, it often goes by the name of Brier score. Yann LeCun has examples on his website of using MSE as the loss function in MNIST neural networks.

Comment: @Dave you can use Brier Score in Sklearn. And there is a difference between Brier Score and MSE. Brier Score is calculated based on probabilities of the predicted and real values (that is the reason it can be used in a classification context), and MSE is calculated in the actual predicted and real values.

Comment: @Murilo Those sound exactly the same to me. Could you please elaborate on what makes them different?

Comment: @Dave The equations are the same, but used with different "values". In the classification case (Brier Score) you use a probability value (something between 0 and 1), while in the case of regression (MSE) you use a real number (forecast electricity consumption for example).

Answer (score 5):

According to [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html):

> This model optimizes the log-loss function using LBFGS or stochastic gradient descent.

[Log-loss](https://web.archive.org/web/20200429173502/http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Log_Loss) is basically [the same as cross-entropy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913508/what-is-the-difference-between-cross-entropy-and-log-loss-error/50926471#50926471).

There is no way to pass another loss function to `MLPClassifier`, so you cannot use MSE. But `MLPRegressor` uses MSE, if you really want that.

However, the general advice is to stick to cross-entropy loss for classification, it is said to have some advantages over MSE. So you may just want to use `MLPClassifier` as is for your classification problem.